# Can I harvest celery a stalk at a time?

Tags: vegetables, harvesting

I've got a chicken in the pot and some (young) celery plants in the garden. Will it damage the plant if I go out and cut a couple of the (small) outer stalks to add a little extra flavor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, in my experience, harvesting one or two of the small outer stalks won't harm a young plant - it should continue to grow quite happily. Bon appétit!

Comment: Thanks! I've got few small stalks and some of those big fragrant leaves doing their thing right now. Nothing like fresh homegrown veg with fresh homegrown chicken!